# How to implement large kernel box filter shader fast?

Tags: android, opengl-es, filter, shader

The box filter kernel size is about 60x60. I have already learned dividing it by two direction, horizontal and vertical. And the interpolation optimization is also used. But the speed is still not fast enough on Android(Galaxy Nexus). Is there any way to implement and optimize the box filter shader?

Comment: Is it minification or magnification?

Comment: Use summedarea tables (SATs): http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch08.html

Comment: @keltar, it is minification. Anything helpful for optimization?

Comment: @JamesZhao well, sampling from higher mip levels (texture2DLod) could significantly improve performance. How exactly depends on your box kernel/mask. It would be simpler to understand your specifics if you'll post actual shader code.

Comment: @Vertexwahn thanks for your suggestion. SAT is wonderful for solving my problem.

Comment: @keltar thanks. I have found a solution by Vertexwahn's answer. Using SAT is a good idea for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use summed-area tables (SATs): [Summed-Area Variance Shadow Maps](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch08.html).